# divide one columns into several columns rdlc report

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I need to show one columns data on multi columns in RDLC report

like

'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under the properties of the report, you can specify the number of colums desired in the body of the report.  This will then allow the data to flow from one column to the next.  I used the matrix table, and it worked perfectly.